# How do I find and use what a function has alerted in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am making a little 'guess the number' game, and I need to find a way to repeat the function based on what it outputs. What I have right now is this:

```
var input = prompt("Please enter a number between 1 and 100!");
var ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);

function numCheck() 
{
    if (input < 1)
        alert("Please enter a valid number!");
    else if (input > 100)
        alert("Please enter a valid number!");
    else if (input > ranNum)
        alert("Try a little lower!");   
    else if (input = typeof stringValue)
        alert("That is not a number!");
    else if (input < ranNum)
        alert("Try a little higher!");
    else
        alert("You got it!");
}

numCheck();
```

I did this using the inspect option on chrome on the page `about:blank`. Now that I have the function, I think I need to use another `if else` statement. It would detect if `numCheck()` output is ***You got it!***" and if it didn't, it would replay the numCheck function, all the way until the player got the correct number.

How would I do it like that? And if there is a simpler way, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle that will use alerts and prompt accessible inside the page (*I am not sure this what you asked for or not - explain more if not*):

**HTML**:

```
<div class="numberguess">
    <input type="text" id="entry" value="" />
    <input type="button" id="send" class="" value="submit" />
</div>

<div id="alert"></div>
```

**JS**:

```
var _alert = document.getElementById('alert');
var ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);

function numCheck(){
    var input = document.getElementById('entry').value;
    if (input < 1 && input > 100)
        _alert.innerText = "Please enter a valid number!";
    else if (input > ranNum)
       _alert.innerText = "Try a little lower!";   
    else if (typeof input != 'string')
        _alert.innerText = "That is not a number!";
    else if (input < ranNum)
        _alert.innerText = "Try a little higher!";
    else
        _alert.innerText = "You got it!";
}

numCheck();

var el = document.getElementById('send');
el.addEventListener('click', function(){
    numCheck();
}, false);
```

Check this as live exp: [**Jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/am3eL8ma/)

Comment: Can you explain the var al = document... to me? I'm quite a beginner and am trying to learn from everything I can.

Comment: We just get the element and cache it into a variable (with any name you like, in this case `el`) for later use. If this is what you asked for please set it as an answer for other viewers

Answer (score 0):

You need a looping mechanism that will keep prompting the user to input another value.

```
var ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);

function numCheck() 
{
    var input = prompt("Please enter a number between 1 and 100!");

    if (input === null)
        return false; // user pressed "cancel"

    if (input == ranNum) {
        alert("You got it!");
        return false;
    }

    if (input < 1)
        alert("Please enter a valid number!");
    else if (input > 100)
        alert("Please enter a valid number!");
    else if (input > ranNum)
        alert("Try a little lower!");
    else if (input < ranNum)
        alert("Try a little higher!");
    else
        alert("That is not a number!");
    return true; // continue looping
}

while(numCheck());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use looping like this code below

```js
var input; // var to hold user input
var ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
var win = false; // var if we want to ask another input
var trycount = 0; // don't want to ask for input forever

function numCheck() 
{
    if (input*1 != input) // check if number first
        alert("That is not a number!");
    else if (input < 1) // check lower bound
        alert("Please enter a valid number!");
    else if (input > 100) // check upper bound
        alert("Please enter a valid number!");
    else if (input > ranNum) // tell a hint
        alert("Try a little lower!");   
    else if (input < ranNum) // tell a hint
        alert("Try a little higher!");
    else{
        alert("You got it!");
        win = true; // end the user prompt
    }
}

while (!win && trycount < 3){ // while wrong guesses and below 3 tries
  input = prompt("Please enter a number between 1 and 100! (" + ranNum + ")");
  trycount++; // count the try
  numCheck();
}
```